# SPRING, Как получить connection из Hikari пула

Tags: spring

Я подумал, что не плохо бы подгружать настройки из БД для своей программы, но столкнулся с трудностью. Не понимаю как получить connection из пула.
Пробовал вот так, но возвращается **null**

```
@Autowired 
JdbcTemplate JdbcTemplate;
Connection conn = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
```

Эта конструкция замечательно работает в классах с аннотацией **@RestController** с замаплеными методами **@PostMapping(value = "/auth")**

Вроде пул есть, все работает, к БД обращается. Подскажите как вытащить **connection** в обычном классе ?

Добавлено:

Попробовал **@Component** и  **@Service** для класса все равно **null**

```
@Service
//@Component
public class GlobalConfig  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalConfig.class);

        @Autowired
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        public void loadConfiguration() {

            try {
                Connection conn = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
                String sql = "SELECT json FROM configuration WHERE id = 1";
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                while (rs.next() ) {
                    logger.error(rs.getString("json"));
                }
                if(conn!=null) conn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }
```

**Main.class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static int IDLE_TIMEOUT = 10;
    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx =  SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
        new GlobalConfig().loadConfiguration();
    }
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.type= com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://11.11.11.11:3306/gps
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5
```

---

Все теперь я понял что тут к чему. Я попробовал внедрить с помощью **@Autowired** в Main класс, но тоже вернулся null. Сработала конструкция:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx =  SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
        ctx.getBean(GlobalConfig.class).loadConfiguration();
}
```

И добавил:

```
@Service
public class GlobalConfig
```

Большое спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Ну, тогда показывайте конфигурацию контекста, код инициализации контекста и код класса, в котором пытаетесь сделать связывание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NullPointerException` падает по причине того, что Вы создаёте  экземпляр класса через конструктор `GlobalConfig`, а не средствами `spring`. Вам необходимо сделать замену

```
 new GlobalConfig().loadConfiguration();
```

на

```
ctx.getBean(GlobalConfig.class).loadConfiguration();
```

Answer (score 1):

Аннотация `@Autowired` работает только в бинах, поэтому ваш класс должен быть аннотирован с помощью `@Component`, `@Service` или каким-либо другим образом помечен для обработки контейнером Spring.

**UPDATE:**

Объект `GlobalConfig` должен создаваться контейнером Spring, а не оператором `new`. Или внедрите его с помощью аннотации `@Autowired` в поле класса `Main` или получите из контекста методом [getBean()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-).

Answer (score 1):

1. Вам не нужен `Connection`. Суть пула соединений как раз в том, чтобы логика работы с соединениями оставалась в деталях реализации пула и не касалась пользователя, использующего его API.
2. Для вызова запросов у `JdbcTemplate` есть метод `query`.
3. Не используйте аннотацию `@Autowired` на полях класса. Используйте ее на сеттерах или на конструкторе.

Comment: Последнее спорно. В частности, это мешает использовать кодогенераторы, типа [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, вы не сможете нормально провести юнит-тестирование компонентов, в частности, мокировать объекты.

Comment: Что помешает мне использовать с юнит-тестом тестовую конфигурацию, в которой подменены необходимые бины? Или `MockitoJUnitRunner`?